# New to UV maps and unwrapping in general, need help

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I'm trying to unwrap a simple model so I could texture paint it. However I really don't understand the process of how to unwrap a model, especially the whole marking seams thing. I only use Project From View, which I think is not optimal when unwrapping certain models (especially complex ones). I've watched tutorials and can't seem to get the gist of UV unwrapping. I'm trying to unwrap the inside of the model, but it gives me weird shapes and sizes. Can anyone tell me how can I unwrap the inside of a model? or better yet, unwrap in general? Thank you!

Here is the picture for reference:
[image: Simple model]

Here is also the .blend file in case anyone wants to show pictures of properly unwrapping this model:

[House WIP.blend](http://www.easysend.to/3fa)

Comment: UV unwrapping can be an art in and of itself. If all you are doing is texture painting in the 3D view, I would recommend just using the Smart UV Project. The advantage is that this will unwrap your model sufficiently so you can paint in the 3D view. The disadvantage is that the 2D layout of the UVs won't be very intelligible, so you won't be able to paint in the 2D view. If you only plan to paint in the 3D view, this will work fine for you.

Comment: Well, I was planning to have my textures painted in Photoshop since I'm more comfortable than in Blender's built in painting stuff.

Comment: Ah right. Well yes, then you do need an ineligible 2D result. Looking at your model though (lots of sharp angles) you might get a fairly good result from the Smart UV Unwrap option. Give it a go, see what it looks like (save first, as it will erase you existing UV map).

Comment: If you are more comfortable with the Project from View, then select all the faces on a side and then project them at the same time, and then place them off to a side of the uv editor away from the center of the view. Repeat until you have all your projections, adn then when you select all your faces you will see all the uv islands there in the editor - you can then arrange them and scale them so that you might better understand in Photoshop.